# receiving response from post() with JQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I had a script working using Ajax (POST method) via plain Javascript.
Now I'm trying to learn JQuery as it seems easier but I am having problem with the response of a request

```
$.post('ajax/wrapper.php', {'desc':$('#description').val()},
        function(data){
            $('#something').html(data);
        });
```

When I do that the request is successfully sent. I can see the changes on my DB but the response is not showing up in div#something.
I also tried

```
...
   $('#something').html($(data));
...
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you see the response in the firebug?

Comment: You can debug this using a few techniques.  The first thing I would recommend doing is downloading Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).  Use this to determine that the request is actually being sent, and data is coming back correctly.  Next, set a breakpoint on the Javascript on the callback function in your browser.  See what is in `data`.  It might not also hurt to statically set the parameter for `.html()`, just to make sure you have the right element selected correctly and what not.

Comment: `{desc:$('#description').val()}` no need of quotes around `desc`

Comment: what kind of response you are expecting

Comment: @3nigma, it shouldn't matter either way.

Comment: I know the data is sent correctly cause the page receiving the request is updating the database (and if I refresh the page I can see the changes). Using plain Javascript it's working correctly

Comment: @Riskz, yes, but did you set the breakpoint to see what data is hitting the callback?  Did you try putting some static data in the `.html()` function's first parameter?  Go through all of these steps, then report back to us.

Comment: it works with static data, I'll triple check the code which returns the response

Comment: Ok commenting out the following line worked:
header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=iso-8859-1");
But I always needed to do that on my ajax requested pages (and that does work if I don't use JQuery).

Comment: can i see the php code that you echo some thing back to your javascript .

Comment: I tried with a file only containing the header (specifying charset iso-8859) and a short text (either echo or html plain text). It only worked without the header request.
It seems like I forgot to specify JQuery charset for the request.
Anyway, I changed everything to utf-8 as I heard its becoming spreadly used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> commenting out the following line worked: header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=iso-8859-1")

See [this document](http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests) and the `dataType` parameter in [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). You should either return HTML with a text/html MIME type, or set the `dataType` parameter to 'html':

```
$.ajax('ajax/wrapper.php', {
    data: {'desc':$('#description').val()},
    dataType: 'html',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        $('#something').html(data);
    }
}).then(console.log); // debug
```

The first is preferable, as you really are returning HTML, and text/html is the correct MIME for that.

Comment: I changed everything to utf-8 to avoid future headaches, but your answer is correct, I had to take a look at JQuery's dataType and charsets.

Answer (score 0):

you can try it this way too

```
var jqxhr = $.post("ajax/wrapper.php",{desc:$('#description').val()}, function(data) {
      alert("success");
    });
```

show the data in the `success` callback

```
jqxhr.complete(function(data){
  $('#something').html(data);
});
```

Comment: Tried. having the same issue. Apparently the following line on wrapper.php is the problem:
 header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=iso-8859-1");

Answer (score 0):

You might to use the $.load

```
$("#something").load('ajax/wrapper.php', {'desc':$('#description').val()} );
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Doesn't load() work with GET method?
Anyway, I will need to do more things apart from changing #something's inner html, so I think it'll be easier to use post()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.post('ajax/wrapper.php', {'desc':$('#description').val()},
        function(data){
            $('#something').html(data);
        }, "html");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$('#something').html($.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "ajax/wrapper.php",
  async: false
 }).responseText)
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: This is extremely poor practice.  You should not be making synchronous requests without a very good reason.

Comment: I just answered the question. Without asynchronous request you can't do this.

Comment: It worked, but I'm expecting to make it work using $.post() method (shouldn't it work either way?)